# Using a child's name before the Brit Milah

Tags: names, children-parenting, brit-milah, ayin-hara-evil-eye

I avoid telling my baby's name to other people before the Brit Milah or nomination for a girl.

Is there a halakhic source for this? Precedence? Or is it just superstition?

Comment: http://shaashuim.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/not-naming-a-boy-until-the-bris/

Comment: http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=34658